# Screen does not close even though Caliburn says it's deactivated and closed

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

When tyring to close a Screen (`MyViewModel`) itself with `this.TryClose()` Caliburn logs that it gets deactivated and closed:

> Caliburn INFO: [2016-12-12T14:43:05.4275321+01:00] Deactivating MyViewModel.
>
> Caliburn INFO: [2016-12-12T14:43:05.4275321+01:00] Closed MyViewModel.

But the Screen does not close. It's still there and I even can interact with the buttons on it.

The Screen is activated inside a conductor class:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    // [...]
    ChangeActiveItem(new MyViewModel(), false);
    // [...]
}
```

When I now try to close the active Screen (which is at this point the `MyViewModel`) from the conductor class with:

```
ActiveItem.TryClose();
```

It gets closed properly.

So How is it possible that the Screen does not get closed when using `this.TryClose()` inside its class, even though Caliburn says it is closing the Screen. But it gets closed properly when trying to close it from the conductor class?
Funny is that I have another ViewModel with the exact same code and there it works as expected.

**Note:**
Inside the `MyViewModel` class I call the `this.TryClose()` in the `OnActivate()` method:

```
protected override void OnActivate()
{
   base.OnActivate();
   // do some stuff
   this.TryClose();
}
```

So basically the screen should pop up and close instantly.

**Another Note:**
When I try calling `ActiveItem.TryClose()` in the conductor after calling the `this.TryClose()` in `MyViewModel` the call in the conductor stops working too, with the logging message from Caliburn:

> Caliburn INFO: [2016-12-12T14:57:11.9553219+01:00] TryClose requires a parent IConductor or a view with a Close method or IsOpen property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it seems that the `this.TryClose()` call comes in too fast after activating the Screen. When putting a `Task.Delay(50)` before the `TryClose()` call it works just fine.
The reason that it worked in the other ViewModel with the same code is that there the code needs a bit more time to execute.

Still don't know the exact reason why Caliburn acts like that.